# Python try except error, program crashes

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, try-catch, try-except

```
def install_build(install_info,source_url=None):
    if source_url is None:
        try:
            version_no = install_info["version_number"]
            build_no = install_info["build_number"]
            if version_no is None or build_no is None:
                raise ValueError("Please specifiy the value(s) for either the source_url or version number and the build number")
        except KeyError:
            print("You are missing either or both of these keys: version number or build number")
        # If the necessary parameters are present, call the method to install the build
        install_build_on_server(version_no,build_no,source_url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    install_build(    
        {   
            "product_type":"abc",
            "username":"def",
            "version_number":None,
            "build_number":"123",
            "password":"xyz"
        }   
        )
```

The above method tries to install a build either from a source url [of the installer] or by collectively taking the build and version number and queries the build repository, gets the repository and installs the build. Thus, either the source url can be None or the version_number and build_number can be None not both. I have written the error handling for the same. But my application fails to handle the error for the above scenario. Could any one let me know what i am missing?

Here is the output of the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    "password":"xyz"
  File "test.py", line 7, in install_build
    raise ValueError("Please specifiy the value(s) for either the source_url or version number and the build number")
ValueError: Please specifiy the value(s) for either the source_url or version number and the build number
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if version_no is None or build_no is None:
```

should be

```
if version_no is None and build_no is None:
```

Comment: If i use the and condition, instead of or, it does not print the error message, i mean the exception is not raised.

Comment: My case is, both should have string values. so if version_no is None and build_no has value, "AND" condition fails

Answer (score 0):

Check both with and :
if version_no is None and build_no is None:

Since version_no you are passing is None which raises a Value error in (OR) part.Either change the condition or pass a value other than None in both version_no and build_no.

Comment: If i use the and condition, instead of or, it does not print the error message, i mean the exception is not raised. My case is, both should have string values. so if version_no is None and build_no has value, "AND" condition fails